# Monodromy associated to a meromorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, covering-spaces

I ask for some hint/help about finding the monodromy homomorphism of a holomorphic map $g: \Bbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}\rightarrow \Bbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$ locally defined by
$$
f(z) = \frac{27z^2(z-1)^2}{4(z^2-z+1)^3}
$$

I see that $deg(g) = 6$ and that we have two ramification points $\infty$ and $0$ with three points in the fiber of $0$, each of multiplicity 2 and two point in the fiber of $\infty$, each of multiplicity 3. Call this branch locus $B$ and consider $p\notin B$.

Hence, by Riemann Existence theorem, we get a monodromy homomorphism

$$
\rho:\pi_{1}(\mathbb{P}^1\smallsetminus B, p)\simeq \Bbb{Z}*\Bbb{Z}*\Bbb{Z}*\Bbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathcal{S}_6
$$
with transitive image. I know that the loop around multiplicity 2 -points should be 2-cycle, and similarly loops around multiplicity 3-points should be mapped to 3-cycle.
But how can I determine the exact permutation for each homotopy class generator?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: I'm confused, don't you have $\mathbb{P}^1\setminus B=\mathbb{A}^1\setminus\{0\}$ whose $\pi_1$ is just $\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I believe that $B$ is made of 5 distinct points, so $\Bbb{P}^1\smallsetminus B$ is homotopically equivalent to a bouquet of 4 circles. Don't you agree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the derivative of $f(z)$ vanishes at the points $-1$, $0$, $1/2$, $1$, $2$, and $\infty$.  The images of these points are the values $0$ and $1$.

It also seems to me that the derivative of $1/f(1/w)$ vanishes at $-1$, $1/2$, $2$, and the points $\exp(\pm \pi i / 3)$.  The images of these are again $0$ and $1$ (but in the $w$-plane).

So I believe that the branch locus $B$ (in the $z$-plane) consists of the points $0$, $1$, and $\infty$.  The fundamental group of you want is that of $\mathbb{CP}^1 - B = \mathbb{C} - \{0, 1\}$, namely a free group of rank two.

The easiest monodromy to compute is the one about zero in the $z$-plane.  So, take a circle of radius $r$ (with $r$ very small, positive, and real) and find the roots of $f(z) = r\exp(i\theta)$, as a function of $\theta$.  As we walk around the circle, these six roots permute in the desired fashion.

Comment: Thank you, now I got it. It seems to me still very hard to find roots above the loop around zero. Am I missing something?

Comment: There is a double root at $z = 0$.  So, look at $\pm \epsilon$.  These are (almost!) sent to $r = 27\epsilon^2 / 4$ (up to error of size at most $O(\epsilon^3)$).  Thus (check!) the equation $f(z) = r$ has two roots near zero.  We now walk along the loop about zero.  The result will be that the two roots (at approximately $\pm \epsilon$) will switch places.  This is because (check!) in a small disk about zero, we have that $f(z) \sim 27 z^2 / 4$. Best -

Comment: I should mention - it has been ages since I did anything like this carefully.  So, while I *think* it is correct, I don't *know* it is correct.  So you should check it all until you understand it to your own satisfaction.

Comment: Nice! This kind of analytic approach was out of my confort zone! Thank you! Anyway, I solved it up by geometrical argument and combinatorially. Thank you because the whole topic is now much clearer to me.